# Unintended Event Listener result returned

Tags: javascript, ios, database, titanium

I am using Titanium to build an iOS app. I am attempting to have an alphabetical list displayed in a tableView. When  a specific row is selected I want to pass the row information to a new window. The code I have displays the list alphabetically in groups with headers and I have an alphabetical scrollbar that when a letter is selected the list moves to that letter. However, when ANY row is selected, they all send the information for the last row in the database. I thought that I needed to have a title element in the row with a text property, then I could have an tableview.addEventListener that grabbed that title and passed it on, but it doesn't work. Here is the code I am using, if someone could please look and see where I am going wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
var db = (function() {
var api   = {};
    api.all_item_names = function() {
        var conn = Ti.Database.install('mydb.sqlite','clients');
        var results = [];
        var resultSet = conn.execute('select * from clients order by clientname asc');
        while ( resultSet.isValidRow()) {
            results.push({
            clientname:  resultSet.fieldByName('clientname'),
        });
        resultSet.next();
    }
    resultSet.close();
    return results;
};
return api;
}());

var tvrow;
var curheader   = 'A';
var list    = [];
var index   = [];
var data   = [];
var isAndroid   = (Titanium.Platform.name == 'android');

list = ( db.all_item_names() );

for ( var ipos=0; ipos<list.length;ipos++){
    if( list[ipos].clientname[0] != curheader){
        curheader = list[ipos].clientname[0];

        tvrow = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
            height:    40,
            path:'clientdetail.js' ,
            client: list[ipos],
            header:    curheader 
            });
        index.push({title:curheader, index:ipos});
    } else {
        tvrow = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
            height:40,
            path:'clientdetail.js' ,
            client: list[ipos]});
        }   

var title= Titanium.UI.createLabel({ 
    left:    5, 
    top:     2, 
    height:  40, 
    color:   '#000', 
    font: {fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold', fontFamily: (isAndroid?'sans-serif':'Helvetica Neue')}, 
    text:    list[ipos].clientname });
    tvrow.add(title);
    data.push(tvrow);
}

var tableView = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    data:            data,
    index:           index,
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    separatorStyle:  Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.GROUPED,
    top:             1,
    width:           '99%'
});

tableView.addEventListener('click', function(e)
    {
        if (e.rowData.path)
        {
            var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
                url:e.row.path,
                title:title.text
            });

        var clientlist = title.text;
        win.clientlist = clientlist;
        Ti.UI.currentTab.open(win);
    }
});

win.add(tableView);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the loop you use. You are assigning everything to the value at index `ipos` which in the end is `list.length` (or the last value) so that is why you always get that one. To get around this, usually a closure is used and the value is passed in, like this:

```
for ( var ipos=0; ipos<list.length;ipos++){
 (function(i){
  if( list[i].clientname[0] != curheader){
   curheader = list[i].clientname[0];

   tvrow = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
    height:    40,
    path:'clientdetail.js' ,
    client: list[i],
    header:    curheader 
   });
   index.push({title:curheader, index:i});
  } else {
   tvrow = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
    height:40,
    path:'clientdetail.js' ,
    client: list[i]
   });
  }   

  var title= Titanium.UI.createLabel({ 
   left:    5, 
   top:     2, 
   height:  40, 
   color:   '#000', 
   font: {fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold', fontFamily: (isAndroid?'sans-serif':'Helvetica Neue')}, 
   text:    list[i].clientname 
  });
  tvrow.add(title);
  data.push(tvrow);
 })(ipos);
}
```

---

*edit*

I believe you were probably getting the wrong title in your new window as well as it accessed the last available `title`. There is however an exposed `title` available to your event listener. It is located at `e.row.client.clientname` (although it might be in `e.rowData..` from the looks of it) I believe, which means you should access that for the currently selected title on click

```
var tableView = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
 data:            data,
 index:           index,
 backgroundColor:'transparent',
 separatorStyle:  Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.GROUPED,
 top:             1,
 width:           '99%'
});

tableView.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
 if (e.rowData.path)
 {
  var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
   url:e.row.path,
   title:e.row.client.clientname
  });

  var clientlist = e.row.client.clientname ? e.row.client.clientname : "No client name";
  win.clientlist = clientlist;
  Ti.UI.currentTab.open(win);
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Travis, but now that my label called title is inside the function, when I reference it in my tableView.addEventListener the title variable is not found. I tried to put the tableView and Listener inside the function and it didn't work either. Sorry I am being so thick about understanding what I need to do. Would you help me again?

Comment: Good edits. Could you be a bit more explicit about the fact that the closure isn't required, and quickly suggest when it should be used and when it shouldn't? I worry that others will come, read this answer, and think the solution is always to introduce a closure.

Comment: @DawsonToth - The closure *is* required to close over the for loop iterator. The extended edit was also required in order to get proper values during the event, and could have been a separate question because it addressed a separate issue than originally brought up. The solution in these situations is to use a closure in order to preserve the iterator's value.

Comment: No. There's no inner delayed context (such as an event listener) that looks at a variable mutated by the loop. The behavior is the same with or without the closure. His misbehavior was from looking at the "var title", which was of course the last value. (His example is also missing a bracket, presumably after the "var title" and before the table view's creation.)

Comment: I know I am not, based on many re-readings of the question and your answer. Please see my answer, and run the code. I am not interested in creating a flame war, so I will not be posting any more on this question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27750/discussion-between-dawson-toth-and-travis-j)

Answer (score 0):

The wrong title is entirely due to referencing the "title" variable. Instead, you should utilize the e.rowData or e.index to determine which row was clicked. "title" will always be the last title you created.

Consider the following example the demonstrates in a simpler way both your bug, and the solution. Note that wrapping the row creating for loop in a function call will NOT help you fix this.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({ backgroundColor: '#fff' });

var rows = [], titles = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({ height: 40 });
    titles.push('Title ' + i);
    var title = Ti.UI.createLabel({ text: titles[i], textAlign: 'center', color: '#000' });
    row.add(title);
    rows.push(row);
}

var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    data: rows
});
table.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    alert('WRONG: You clicked ' + title.text + '\n'
        + 'RIGHT: You clicked ' + titles[evt.index]);
});
win.add(table);

win.open();
```